# Array summing method not working // javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to sum (ie. 4+15+10 etc... = total) the below array. I believe I'm using the right code but it doesn't seem to be working. Can someone take a look at it for me?

```
function beginhere() {
var arr = [4,15,10,7,6,18,1,18,8,45,55,16,9,19,11,13,14];
var total =0
var i =0
for(i < arr.length; i++) {
total += arr[i][1];
}
document.getElementById("thismessage").innerHTML = i;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need just the element, without another index, because you have an array with single values and not an array of arrays.

```
total += arr[i];
//             ^^^
```

and the right start value for the [`for` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)

```
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
//   ^^^^^
```

and you need to assign the `total` instead of the loop variable `i`.

```
document.getElementById("thismessage").innerHTML = total;
//                                                 ^^^^^
```

```js
function beginhere() {
    var arr = [4, 15, 10, 7, 6, 18, 1, 18, 8, 45, 55, 16, 9, 19, 11, 13, 14],
        total = 0,
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        total += arr[i];
    }
    document.getElementById("thismessage").innerHTML = total;
}

beginhere();
```

```html
<div id="thismessage"></id>
```

Comment: And also `document.getElementById("thismessage").innerHTML = total;
`

Comment: tysm this worked :) quick question: why do I need to assign I =0 in the for statement when I already assigned it to 0 at the beginning?

Comment: @Karl: You don't *have* to, but you *do* have to include all three parts of the `for` statement header, to satisfy syntax. So you *could* do `for( ; i < arr.length; i++)` (note that early `;`, denoting an empty init clause). But idiomatically, unless there's a good reason not to, you should include all three parts of the `for` header *in* the `for` header.

Answer (score 2):

1. For loop syntax was wrong.its a `for(i=0; i<length; i++)`
2. Second problem was addition with array arguments. `total += arr[i];`
3. last one the you are not print  the total value.you just print the increment .but the not use because is outside loop

```js
function beginhere() {
var arr = [4,15,10,7,6,18,1,18,8,45,55,16,9,19,11,13,14];
var total =0
var i =0
for(i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
total += arr[i];
}
console.log(total);
}

beginhere();
```

Another method [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) [`Arrow function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) simply use like this

```js
var arr = [4,15,10,7,6,18,1,18,8,45,55,16,9,19,11,13,14];
 var res = arr.reduce((a,b) => a+b ,0)
 
 console.log(res)
```

Comment: Good answer. Note: You don't need the `, 0` on the `reduce`. If you leave it off, the first call will pass the first two elements as `a` and `b`, which is great when summing.

Comment: And as you're using an arrow function, may as well use the concise form: `arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b);` (or `arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);` if you want to pass that `0`).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks for your suggestion . I m not well in arrow function writing .  I was Notedown your point ..

Answer (score 1):

A few corrections:

- You are missing a semicolon at the beginning of your `for` loop;
- You don't need the extra `[1]` after your `arr[i]` access; and
- You probably meant to set your content to `total` instead of `i`.

A few other suggestions:

- Use `textContent` instead of `innerHTML` when you don't plan on inserting tags; and
- Place `var i = 0` *inside* of your `for` loop (this is common practice).

```js
function beginhere() {
  var arr = [4, 15, 10, 7, 6, 18, 1, 18, 8, 45, 55, 16, 9, 19, 11, 13, 14]
  var total = 0
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    total += arr[i]
  }
  document.getElementById("thismessage").textContent = total
}

beginhere()
```

```html
<p id="thismessage"></p>
```